# How can I correctly create my own function to take a photo in Xamarin forms after 10 seconds?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am following this project https://github.com/ThatCSharpGuy/Forms-FullCameraPage to implement a camera in xamarin forms. it works without any problem but i would like to create my own void to take the photo. The only thing i have changed in that project to my current one is that I have made the `CameraPage` to a Contentpage XAML instead of a class.

The idea is to make a function so the photo gets taken in 10 seconds and i want to control this in my shared code if it is possible.

if we look at the code that i have added this is what i got so far.

```
public CameraPage()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        loadCameraFunction (); //so this is the function that i created myself
}

//i added this and put the same value into them as the ones in `SetPhotoResult`
byte[] image;
int width = -1;
int height = -1;

//the void
async void loadCameraFunction()
{
   await Task.Delay (10000); //wait 10 sec for the photo to be taken
   SetPhotoResult(image, width, height); //i add the byte[] and two ints i created above that has the same value as the ones in SetPhotoResult
}

    public delegate void PhotoResultEventHandler(PhotoResultEventArgs result);

    public event PhotoResultEventHandler OnPhotoResult;


    public void SetPhotoResult(byte[] image, int width = -1, int height = -1)
    {
        OnPhotoResult?.Invoke(new PhotoResultEventArgs(image, width, height));
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        OnPhotoResult?.Invoke(new PhotoResultEventArgs());
    }

    public class PhotoResultEventArgs : EventArgs
    {

        public PhotoResultEventArgs()
        {
            Success = false;
        }

        public PhotoResultEventArgs(byte[] image, int width, int height)
        {
            Success = true;
            Image = image;
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
        }

        public byte[] Image { get; private set; }
        public int Width { get; private set; }
        public int Height { get; private set; }
        public bool Success { get; private set; }
    }

}
```

}

Problem i have with this code is that the result from my function seems to be null. It seems like i dont get the image. So my question is: Is the `SetPhotoResult` function what i need to call in order to take the photo? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetPhotoResult` should be called once the photo is taken. If all you want to happen is that a photo is taken 10 seconds after you hit the "Take Photo" button on the `FullCameraqPagePage` then you will need to modify the code in the custom renderer. For iOS in the `CameraPageRenderer` class add the following to the end of the `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
await Task.Delay(10000);
var data = await CapturePhoto();
UIImage imageInfo = new UIImage(data);

(Element as FullCameraPage.CameraPage).SetPhotoResult(
        data.ToArray(),
        (int)imageInfo.Size.Width,
        (int)imageInfo.Size.Height);
```

This is the same code that is run when you click the circular button on the CameraPage but with the delay added.

It may also be a good idea to remove the cancel (x in the upper left) and the circular button that actually takes the photo (the "Take Photo" button on the first page only loads the camera page, it does not take the photo). To remove those buttons so the user can't interrupt your picture (well, they still can if they close the app) then remove these two lines of code from the `SetupUserInterface` method of `CameraPageRenderer`:

```
View.Add(takePhotoButton);
View.Add(cancelPhotoButton);
```

Of course you can remove all code related to those two buttons as well.

For Android the same idea should apply. Just add the following to the `OnElementChanged` method in the Android `CameraPageRenderer` class:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
        var bytes = await TakePhoto();
        (Element as CameraPage).SetPhotoResult(bytes, liveView.Bitmap.Width, liveView.Bitmap.Height);
```

and to get rid of the the manual take photo button, remove the following from the `SetupUserInterface` method:

```
mainLayout.AddView(capturePhotoButton);
```

EDIT: To do it all in the shared code:

Add a class property to  `CameraPage` of type `Action`:

```
public Action TakePicture { get; set; }
```

Set the code for the `Action` in CameraPageRenderer:

(Android):

```
(Element as CameraPage).TakePicture = async () =>
{
     var bytes = await TakePhoto();
    (Element as CameraPage).SetPhotoResult(bytes, liveView.Bitmap.Width, liveView.Bitmap.Height);
};
```

(iOS):

```
(Element as CameraPage).TakePicture = async () =>
{
    var data = await CapturePhoto();
    UIImage imageInfo = new UIImage(data);

    (Element as FullCameraPage.CameraPage).SetPhotoResult(data.ToArray(),
        (int)imageInfo.Size.Width,
        (int)imageInfo.Size.Height);
};
```

Then in `CameraPage` again:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    if (TakePicture != null)
    {
           await Task.Delay(5000);
           TakePicture();
    }
}
```

That oughta do it.

Comment: Yea i could do that but I want to control it in my shared code. The reasoning for that is because I want to make it more advanced later on so that is kinda of a must-have. The photoclick-event is the `CapturePhoto` right? Can I reach it somehow via a dependency or something like that in my frontend?

Comment: yes, this line in the iOS page renderer actually gets the data for the photo: `var data = await CapturePhoto();` but you still need to call the following two lines to get the photo pack to your original page.

Comment: So how can I reach that exact function on my original page? I am used to working with dependency service and interfaces and that way I can easily run the `CapturePhoto` function but in a renderer i am not sure how to make it possible. I want to do it via a void in the contentpage,

Comment: If all you need to control from the shared code is the delay time, you could add a class level property to `CameraPage` for the delay time and then use that for the delay in the custom renderer with `await Task.Delay((Element as FullCameraPage.CameraPage).Delay);`

Comment: In my case i dont want to await it in the renderer because i want to add more functionality later on. So what I need is to reach the "photo-taken-event-click" and use it in a void on my contentpage. But maybe that will be hard to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, then add a delegate property to `CameraPage` and assign the delegate on the renderer with the code to call the necessary methods in the renderer.

Comment: Edited answer to show delegate method of doing this.

Comment: Just realized that on iOS wuth my edit above, the first time it won't work because of asking for permission to use the camera seems to stop the process. So ask for permission in the AppDelegate class instead.

Comment: Very appreciated! Checking it out :) Give me a few minutes

Comment: To ask for permission in AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching: `var authorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.GetAuthorizationStatus(AVMediaType.Video);
   if (authorizationStatus != AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
   {
    AVCaptureDevice.RequestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaType.Video, (accessGranted) => {});
   }` and remove call to `await AuthorizeCameraUse();` in `ViewDidLoad` method of iOS `CameraPageRenderer`

Comment: Trying to upvote it as well but i am new to this forum so it does not let me. Once again thanks a lot for this

Comment: No problem! thanks for letting me know this is a workable solution for you.

Comment: trying to take the project the next step by implementing a video now. i just uploaded a thread about it if you want to take a look. the code is very "spread out" as of now though as it is slightly complicated for my programminglevel